# Table height in percentage not working

Tags: html, css, mobile, tablelayout

I am developing a mobile site and trying to use very simple markups.

Below is my code which is giving me problem :

```
<div class="abc">
  <div>&nbsp;</div>
  <table>

  </table>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.abc {height:some-dynamic-value-in-px}

.abc div {height:5%;}
.abc table {height:95%;}
```

Problem is this code worked on all the latest phones.But when I checked on sony ericson (500i)
the table height was coming out of the parent div abc and the UI was distorted.
I checked this site http://www.apptools.com/examples/tableheight.php
and gave height {100%} to body but still no success.
Please let me know where I am going wrong.

Also, when I gave the height in px it worked for all handsets.But I want to know the reason why percentage was not working.

Comment: You're likely to burn a lot of time dialing in subtle details on seemingly endless arrays of mobile platforms. I recommend using something like the [JQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/) designer to generate mobile friendly HTML layouts for you. They've gone through the pain of making layouts look correct on all popular mobile platforms.

Comment: yes I know about Jquery Mobile but for some reasons we are not allowed to use JS so I need to completely rely on HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 0):

If you already know the height of the div, then its better to use fixed dimensions in `px`.

Try to ***avoid*** the complexity, if its not necessary.

And for some browsers, giving `body { height: 100%; }` might not be enough.

```
html, body { height: 100%; }

.abc { height:100%; }
.abc div { height:5%; }
.abc table { height:95%; }
```

Also, dont forget to include the **DOCTYPE** on your webpage.

Comment: I was using percentage so that the layout gets render almost the same on all browsers/hansets. And I have included the DOCTYPE too.I guess working with px is the optimum solution.

Comment: @user1483487, If it is really that important use scripts, to control the dimensions.